# Qt automatic testing of console application

Tags: c++, qt, testing, automated-tests, console-application

I'm currently working on a console application with Qt, and I was wondering, if there is any way to automatically test my application, so I don't have to test everything manually. I've searched the web, but haven't found anything yet.

If there is no way to do this with a preexisting framework, would it be possible to have an extra thread writing to, and reading from `stdin` and checking on this thread if the program is behaving correctly? If yes, how exactly would I do this? (I'm a beginner at everything multithreading)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it’s a console app controlled via stdin, you could write a separate program (maybe using QProcess) to launch it, write commands to its stdin, and read replies from its stdout and/or stderr.  As for testing frameworks, there is a Qt-oriented testing package called Squish, but it might be overkill for your purpose (it’s designed for testing Qt GUIs, I’m not sure what it offers for testing Qt-based console apps)

Comment: Squish is able to access all QObject classes, means you are able to execute methods, check variables etc. Give it a try with trial license. https://www.froglogic.com/de/squish/

Comment: You might look into Python's subprocess management stuff to interact with your application from the python script which would be your test script.